# Adding nodes in a style

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I have the following code, which draws a matrix and then uses the nodes inside the matrix to create new nodes:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes] {
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4 \\
};


%% BEGIN
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
  \node [fit = (m-1-1) (m-1-2), fill=red!7, inner sep=0pt] {};
\end{pgfonlayer}

\node [below of = m-2-2] {foo};
%% END


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I am trying to create a style (called here `fill first cell`) that would add the code between BEGIN and END when used as follows:

```
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes, fill first cell] {...};
```

My few attempts were not very succesful.

I tried using the `append after command` but this caused my matrix to be drawn twice. I think this is due to the fact that I am not actually continuing a path but creating new ones.

I am pretty sure I could get this example to work if I used pgf commands to replicate the role of the `fit` library. However this would be very verbose and not real easy to read/modify.

Is there any way to have the clean interface provided by styles as well as the power of tikz? By this I mean, can I, in a style, instantiate TikZ nodes that depends on the nodes of the matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply styles on nodes in cells very easily with various styles, they are in order of application:

1. `every cell` (the key `cells` appends to `every cell`),
2. `column <number>`,
3. `every odd column`,
4. `every even column`,
5. `row <number>`,
6. `every odd row`,
7. `every even row`,
8. `row <row number> column <column number>`.

I believe you are looking for the last one, i.e. `row 1 column 1`.

With

```
\tikzset{
  fill first cell/.style={
    row 1 column 1/.append style={
      nodes={fill=#1}}},
  fill first cell/.default=red!7
}
```

you can define a style `fill first cell` that adds `fill=red!7` to the nodes in the very first cell of the matrix. You can also use an optional value that is used instead of the default `red!7` color.

If you really want to use your combination, you can add an `append after command` to the matrix as in the example below.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,fit,backgrounds}
\tikzset{
  fill first cell/.style={
    append after command={
      \pgfextra
        \pgfonlayer{background}
          \tikzset{every node/.style=}
          \node[fit=(\tikzlastnode-1-1), inner sep=+0pt, fill=#1] {};
        \endpgfonlayer
      \endpgfextra
    }
  },
  fill first cell/.default=red!7
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes, fill first cell] {
  1 & 2 \\
  3 & 4 \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: This is just an example, not the actual code. I want to create a node that depends on a node.

Comment: @NicolasDudebout Well, instead of `fill=#1` you can use `append after command={{[every node/.style=] node[fit=(\tikzlastnode), inner sep=+0pt, fill=#1] {}}}`. Is that what you want?

Comment: Let me try if that works in my application. If not I will update the example.

Comment: It actually shows one of the problems I have. I cannot use the layers in this context as I am still in the middle of the same path.

Comment: I am having a slight issue described in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131077/adding-tikz-node-in-the-middle-of-a-path-triggers-redrawing

Comment: @NicolasDudebout Ah, interesting, never occurred to me. But yes, then you really can’t use the `pgfonlayer` environment inside a path. I have reverted back my answer. I don’t see another way but to issue your drawing commands (inside the `pgfonlayer` environment) *after* the `\matrix`.

Comment: It seems that the Tikz node inside the pgfextra is to blame. However, if I do a pgfnode it works, so I think this is fixable.

Comment: your previous revision was better. Please revert to it at it really addresses my question. Just add a `\path;` before the `\node` to address the current bug investigated in the other question.

Comment: @NicolasDudebout I somehow missed your comment. I haven’t had a problem with `\pgfextra` before if I included its content in the `pgfinterruptpath` (as recommended by Mark Wibrow). You might edit your question to include the real use-case (i.e. why can’t you simply `fill` the node as I did previously). And why can’t you do it after the matrix? Why do you need `append after command` *and* `pgfonlayer`? [This is \[after all\] what triggered it.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131077/adding-tikz-node-in-pgfextra-triggers-double-drawing-of-containing-path#comment296002_131205)

Comment: I could do it after the matrix. My question was "can I do it in a style". I have updated the example to show why I cannot use fill for example, because I need to use the whole line of a matrix.

Comment: I have added the solution to this issue in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131077/adding-tikz-node-in-the-middle-of-a-path-triggers-redrawing